# How to find permission level for a SPGroup (2010)?

Tags: permissions, groups

I have been trying to find how to find what permission level a group (within SPWeb.Groups) has. But it seems like there is no easy way to do this. Any ideas?

I have tried creating SPRoleAssignment and passing the group to get the RoleDefinitionBindings, but it seems like creating a new instance does not help with finding existing permission level.

Using SPWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup does not give me all the "full permission" groups either.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prints out all the groups for the SPWeb and the group's role names:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server/sites/sitecollection/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb("test"))
    {
        foreach (SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment in web.RoleAssignments)
        {
            if (roleAssignment.Member is SPGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Group: " + roleAssignment.Member.Name);
                foreach (SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition in roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + roleDefinition.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was creating the SPRoleAssignment and passing the group to it for instantiation - silly me :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: this throws an exception if my user permission level is low can any one tell me how solve this.

Comment: @thomas Not sure what you're trying to do... you need permission to view the groups?

Comment: I know this is an old post - he might've solved his problem already, but for anyone finding they need higher privileges to let the code run, just put `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {   ....   }` around any block you find that needs elevated privileges.